# Bad: Progress Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

i have problem about this:

```
private void loadJson(){

    pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data");
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();

    JsonArrayRequest reqData = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, ServerAPI.URL_DATA, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Log.d("volley","response : " + response.toString());
                    for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++)
                    {
                        try {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            ModelData md = new ModelData();
                            md.setNpm(data.getString("npm"));
                            md.setNama(data.getString("nama"));
                            md.setProdi(data.getString("prodi"));
                            md.setFakultas(data.getString("fakultas"));
                            mItems.add(md);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pd.cancel();
                    Log.d("volley", "error : " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(reqData);
}
```

and a i have an error like this:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.androidcrudvolley/com.example.androidcrudvolley.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.setMessage(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a
>   null object reference

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share more code from that Activity -- it looks like `pd` is null because `loadJson` is called before `pd` has been set

Answer (score 1):

What is pd? As the error says you are trying to use pd.setMessage("Mengambil Data") and pd seems to be null. Check if you initialized it before